# UIWebView significant and long CPU usage after ANY JS code executed

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have pretty large HTML I need to render using UIWebView. It's ok.
The problem is **after** calling **ANY** JS code (via stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) WebThread uses 100% CPU for several seconds freezing my app. **Freezes do occur a second after JS executed.**

```
NSString *jsres = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"0"];
```

Image bellow. Green initial CPU usage (let's say it's OK), red ones are after calls to JS.
[image]

Why does this happen and how to avoid it?

Comment: How did you measure this cpu usage? You could Start parallel Threads for different parts of your background Calculations.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this? I’m having the same issue after presenting an SFSafariViewController